# PHP: How to use Stripe webhooks to notify the server of successful payment after subscription trial ends?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe API and Stripe webhooks in my project.

I have everything set up and working fine. in my Stripe account, I have a subscription plan that starts with a `14 day Free Trial`.

after this 14 day free trial, I need to use the Stripe webhook to notify my server of `successfull payment` or `failed payment`.

I tried to use this variable for the successful payment:

```
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

$stripe_c_id = $event_json->data->object->customer;

if ($event_json->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {

//do my stuff here///


}
```

However, as soon as someone subscribes, Stripe sends `invoice.payment_succeeded` through webhooks! But I only need to be notified **After the FREE trial**.

This is causing a slight issue in my system.

So, I was wondering if there's other varible that I have to look for in Stripe webhooks for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is quite confusing. I found this: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle

1. A customer.created event is sent, indicating that a customer record
   was successfully created.
2. A customer.subscription.created event is sent, indicating the
   subscription has been created.
3. An invoice is drafted and then finalized, prior to a charge attempt
   being made. The invoice.created and invoice.finalized events are
   sent, indicating that this invoice was issued for the first billing
   period.
4. A charge.succeeded event is sent, indicating that the customer’s
   payment method was successfully charged.
5. An invoice.payment_succeeded event is sent, indicating that the
   invoice was successfully marked paid.

as it suggested, it'll send the `charge.succeeded` event to indicate the payment was successful.

But why do we need `invoice.payment_succeeded` after that IF the payment was successful?!?

Comment: the use of `@` should be banned.. don't suppress your errors, fix them!

Comment: I'm not supressing any errors. I catch all the errors in my PHP for debugging purposes.

Comment: Try using `customer.subscription.trial_will_end`

Comment: @JamesJuanjie maybe read up on what `@` does..

Comment: You need to read the stripe documentation regarding webhooks, im sure there is more information in the array you named as event_json that will give you a more granular information set. I doubt invoice.payment_succeeded is all there was to see.

Comment: @codisfy, wouldn't that return the `Date` that trial will end?

Comment: @Chris, I can assure you that I have read as much as possible before posting here! and everything led me to `invoice.payment_succeeded`. but that's firing as sson as someone subscribes and ignores the Free trial period.

Comment: @Chris, here's the official Stripe page that explains this: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/invoice-states

Comment: Looking at that page, there are several webhooks you need to be handling.

customer.subscription.created
customer.subscription.trial_will_end
invoice.created
invoice.finalized
invoice.payment_succeeded

Does your webhook script handle this and are you certain you have provided the correct url(s) to stripe in their configs. from what i can tell (I have no access to their api) you can set a url for each webhook which might mean you are missing some or have them set incorrectly. So if you have the first and last webhooks working you would see those only even though the others got sent

Comment: @Chris, that is not the question. the question was why stripe sends `invoice.payment_succeeded` as soon as a customer subscribe to a plan that has a free trial. `invoice.payment_succeeded` should only be sent when a payment is taken from the customers card! with a free trial as it suggests, there shouldn't be any payments taken! i wonder if this is because of testing mode being on!

Comment: @JamesJuanjie In this case (sorry for the previous erroneous comment). You need to revise your question, its not why they are sending the response, its why are they ignoring your trial data. Showing us the code used to build the subscription request might show up some error that you overlooked. Could be a typo.

Comment: @chris, you are correct. i should say why they are ignoring the free trial. However, i've built the subscription plan directly from the stripe dashboard and all i do is to susbcribe/attach the users to that plan via stripe API.

Comment: Please supply the code you use (copy and paste the relevant code from your local source) and include a link to the required pages so we can help you debug. To be honest I found your question because I im working on my own api integration for another company and they have very limited documentation for it. However I'm happy to help where i can but it may take me a little time to get back to you.

Comment: @chris, my code is in my question. that code is being fired by the stripe webhooks.